# Is there a symmetric matrix with integer coefficients of order n?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices

Let $n$ be a positive integer. It is easy to find a symmetric matrix with complex coefficients with order $n$ i.e. $A^n = I$, one can just consider the diagonal matrix with $n$-th roots of units.

A matrix $A$ has order $n$ if it is the smallest positive integer such that $A^n = I$.

But is there a symmetric matrix with integer coefficients with order $n$?

Comment: what about the trivial answers $A=\operatorname{diag}(\pm1,\cdots,\pm1)$ considering all combinations of signs?

Comment: all of those satisfy $A^2 = I$. But I want it for n any positive integer

Comment: why symmetric.?

Comment: It is related to the research I am doing. The algebra generated by a matrix like this would be a interesting example in the theory I am studying. But as it is unpublished complicated stuff it would be very cumbersome and awkward to explain here.

Comment: For completeness, the matrices $A=\operatorname{diag}(\pm1,\cdots,\pm1)$ will satisfy $A^{n}=I$ for all $n$ even. Could prove useful, although is trivial

Comment: Yes, but when one say the order of a matrix one means that n is the smallest number that satisfies the equation

Comment: I see. You could add that requirement in the question, for completeness :).

Comment: You can pretty easily show this is not possible for $2\times2$ matrices and $n$ being any number greater than $1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** Since $A^n = {\bf 1}$, all of its eigenvalues are $n$th roots of unity. But all of the eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix are real. (It could be helpful, too, to remember that symmetric matrices are diagonalizable.)